# how to resolve Apache apachectl[5465]: Segmentation fault (core dumped)?

Tags: apache2

I recently ran an **apt upgrade** and while everything seemed fine, now when I try and get apache2 running I run into the following issues,

```
$ sudo systemctl start apache2
Job for apache2.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status apache2.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

```
$ systemctl status apache2
● apache2.service - The Apache HTTP Server
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/apache2.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2022-02-10 13:35:40 PST; 30s ago
       Docs: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/
    Process: 6919 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/apachectl start (code=exited, status=139)

Feb 10 13:35:39 Mythbox systemd[1]: Starting The Apache HTTP Server...
Feb 10 13:35:40 Mythbox apachectl[6919]: Segmentation fault (core dumped)
Feb 10 13:35:40 Mythbox apachectl[6919]: Action 'start' failed.
Feb 10 13:35:40 Mythbox apachectl[6919]: The Apache error log may have more information.
Feb 10 13:35:40 Mythbox systemd[1]: apache2.service: Control process exited, code=exited, status=139/n/a
Feb 10 13:35:40 Mythbox systemd[1]: apache2.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Feb 10 13:35:40 Mythbox systemd[1]: Failed to start The Apache HTTP Server.
```

```
~$ sudo apachectl configtest
Syntax OK
```

Nothing presents in the error log, and that is with loglevel set to debug, so whatever is happening isn't getting that far. I've tried an **apt reinstall apache2** but that didn't make a difference.

At this point I'm stuck in what to do to figure out what is going on. Any ideas?

Comment: Which error log(s) have you looked at? If there isn’t something in `/var/log/apache2/error.log`, then there should be something in `/var/log/syslog` 

Comment: What version of Ubuntu? Server Desktop or Core version?

Answer (score 11):

On a hunch, I went through and disabled all the apache2 mods, then slowly enabled them, one by one, until I found the one that was causing the crash.

It turned out to be apache2 was trying to load php7.4 and php8.1 which causes the crash. Load just one and it's fine.

Comment: Well this sucks tho. I got php7.4 and php8.1 enabled at same time when upgrading the ubuntu from 18.04 to 20.04... Ouch... *veteran linux sysadmin hitting wall with this, such shame for myself

Comment: You may explain it how you did. I am also facing same situation now.

Comment: A bit late, but the way to do this is to install and configure php7.4-fpm and php8.1-fpm, and remove libapache2-mod-php8.1 and libapache2-mod-php7.4.  You would do this because different sites need to run different versions of php, so you'd put code in the site configurations directing php requests to the appropriate socket. On debian the default location is e.g.  /var/run/php/php8.1-fpm.sock, or you could use a TCP socket (less efficient)

Answer (score 0):

For some people that upgrading to new Ubuntu 20.04, and face segmentation fault because of using ondrej/php/ubuntu build, welll.. you need to disabled one of the mod_php or fully disable them and use php-fpm. That will fix the problem that raised.

Answer (score 0):

I had installed php 7.4 on my Ubuntu 20.0 so apache2 was trying to load php7.4 and php8.1 which was causing the crash. So I uninstalled php version 8.1 from my Ubuntu 20.0 after which apache started working properly.

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar issue with the error message "Apache apachectl[5465]: Segmentation fault (core dumped)" and managed to find a solution that worked for me.

In my case, the problem was related to the php8.2 module. I was able to resolve it by disabling the php8.2 module using the a2dismod command:

```
sudo a2dismod php8.2
```